# Form Builder plugin returns 'undefined' when I submit

Tags: form

Today I wanted to add a contact form to my webpage, and I chose the Form Builder plugin for its ease of use. So far all went well, and I managed to display the form in the page (not that difficult), but when testing the form I got an undefined error.

As of now I have no idea what is undefined. I checked the code, the fields I use (they are all Form Builder fields, the email and the plain text), and I checked the settings of Form Builder.

Can you guys help me out?

The link to my website: www.evinwijninga.com

The code in the template

```
<!-- CONTACT FORM -->

{% set form = craft.formBuilder.getFormByHandle('contactForm') %}
{% set tabs = form.fieldLayout.getFieldLayout().getTabs() %}
{% set pluginScripts = craft.formBuilder.pluginScripts(form) %}

<div class="grid-100">
    <h2>How to contact me</h2>

    <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="{{ form.handle }}" class="formbuilder-form grid-60 prefix-20 suffix-20 {{ form.handle }}" id="{{ form.handle }}" data-parsley-errors-container=".formbuilder-notification"{% if form.hasFileUploads %} enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="formBuilder/entries/saveFormEntry">
        <input type="hidden" name="formredirect" data-redirect="{{form.successPageRedirect}}" value="{{form.redirectUrl}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="formHandle" value="{{form.handle}}">

        {% for tab in tabs %}
        {% set fields = tab.getFields() %}

        <fieldset class="{{loop.index}}">
            <legend>{{ tab.name }}</legend>
            {% for field in fields %}
            {% set input = craft.formBuilder.getInputHtml(field) %}
            <div class="grid-100 grid-parent">{{ input | raw }}</div>
            {% endfor %} 
        </fieldset>
        {% endfor %}

        {# Error/Success Messages #}
        {% if craft.session.hasFlash('error') or craft.session.hasFlash('success') %}
        {% if craft.session.hasFlash('error') %}<div class="formbuilder-notification"><p class="error-message">{{ craft.session.getFlash('error') | raw }}<p></div>{% endif %}
        {% if craft.session.hasFlash('success') %}<div class="formbuilder-notification success"><p class="success-message">{{ craft.session.getFlash('success') | raw }}</p></div>{% endif %}
        {% else %}
        <div class="formbuilder-notification"></div>
        {% endif %}

        <button type="submit" class="grid-100">Submit Message</button>


    </form>
</div>
```

The fields:

[image]

and the settings in Form Builder

[image]

This is the latest error entry. The timestamp however is different than the time when I tested the form (which was later):

[image]

Comment: What's the actual undefined error you're getting?  If you check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files, you'll get the error along with the full stack trace.

Comment: Hi @BradBell, I added a screen shot of the latest error. However I doubt if that is the right one.

Comment: Yeah, that's un-related. Better to delete the `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder, recreate the issue, then look back at the logs again. Will be easier to spot where your issue is, then.

Comment: Sadly no error log is written when I recreate the issue @BradBell

Answer (score 2):

we ran into the same problem. If you remove "admin" on line 12 of /plugins/formbuilder/resources/js/formbuilder-form.js it works.

```
url = '/actions/' + $(this).children('[name=action]').attr('value');
```

We couldn't figure out why the path leads to something which is only accessible with admin-rights.